# MultiLevel list in Asopse Document

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.words

I am working on Asopse Document.
I need multilevel list.I searched in many blogs but no one satisfied my requirement.
I need exactly the below format in aspose document.

```
1.  Main Section1
     1.1    Sub Section1.1
             1.1.1 Sub Section 1.1.1
     1.2    Sub Section 1.2
2   Main Section2
     2.1 Sub Section2.1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to create multilevel lists. This code demonstrates the list up to level two. You can follow the same pattern for more levels.

```
Document doc = new Document();

// Create a list based on one of the Microsoft Word list templates.
Aspose.Words.Lists.List list = doc.Lists.Add(ListTemplate.NumberDefault);

// Completely customize one list level.
ListLevel level1 = list.ListLevels[0];
level1.NumberStyle = NumberStyle.Arabic;
level1.NumberFormat = "\u0000";

ListLevel level2 = list.ListLevels[1];
level2.NumberStyle = NumberStyle.Arabic;
level2.NumberFormat = "\u0000.\u0001";    

DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

builder.ListFormat.List = list;
builder.Writeln("Text1_Level1");
builder.Writeln("Text2_Level1");

builder.ListFormat.ListIndent();
builder.Writeln("Text1_Level2");
builder.Writeln("Text2_Level2");

builder.ListFormat.ListOutdent();
builder.Writeln("Text3_Level1");

builder.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers();

builder.Document.Save("Lists.CreateCustomList.docx");
```

I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: And how to do this for HTML to WORD export ?

Comment: There is a bug for Main Section2 in Java, it would always start with 1.1 insed of 2.1